# The printf doesn't give output until I type a letter and press enter

Tags: c, output, printf

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int main() {
    float g1, g2, c1, c2, dismul, cadd, csub, dis;

    printf("Enter the latitudes of the places (L1 and L2): ");
    scanf("%f %f", &c1 ,&c2);
    printf("Enter the longitudes of the places (G1 and G2): ");
    scanf("%f %f ", &g1, &g2);
    cadd = cos(c1 + c2);
    csub = cos(g2-g1);
    dismul = cadd * csub;
    dis = 3963 * acos(dismul);
    printf("The distance between the places is:%f\n", dis);
    return 0;
}
```

I wrote this code to give distance between two points but when I run it, it does not give the last `printf` until I type any letter and press enter.

Comment: `"%f %f "` -> `"%f %f"`

Comment: Please don't tag unrelated languages! C# is sufficiently different from C that the first couple of lines of code would result in a compiler error, and methods like `printf` and `scanf` don't exist, even with an import.

Comment: OT: generally prefer `double` to `float`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

as already pointed out in comments, on line 9 of your code ( `scanf("%f %f ",&g1,&g2);`)

There is an extra space after the second "`%f`", so scanf() is expecting to read a whitespace after a floating point character.

replace it with

```cpp
scanf("%f %f",&g1,&g2);
```

to fix it.

Comment: It helped a lot. Thank you

Comment: @MeetSingh I don't believe you. Double check again, you must have done wrong something.

Comment: @MeetSingh another possibility is that your c library is broken, but I don't believe this either

Comment: I tested it on my machine with input  `1 2 3 4` for which I am getting final value as `8461.718750`